# OneDrive Android SDK Navigate Available Sites

Tags: android, onedrive

I'm trying to create a list of all current sites a user can access within their tenant and display it so the user can later select what site to upload files to. I'm using the [OneDrive for Android SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android).

```
    client.get()
            .getDrive()
            .getItems(root)
            .getChildren()
            .byId(name)
            .getContent()
            .buildRequest()
            .put(contents, callback);
```

This code currently uploads a file to `root`, which is an id obtained from

```
    client.get()
            .getDrive()
            .getRoot()
            .buildRequest()
```

This obtains the root folder of my onedrive presumably using https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/me. If I upload a file to `root`, the file is placed in the root directory of my OneDrive. I want to upload the file to a site "Test" I created instead of my root drive.

How would I go about finding and selecting a different site to upload my file to?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android) to solve my problem.

Found the relevant MSGraph API endpoint that returns all user sites using [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=
```

Create classes to deserialize JSON:

```
public class Site {

@SerializedName("createdDateTime")
private String createdDateTime;

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("lastModifiedDateTime")
private String lastModifiedDateTime;

@SerializedName("name")
private String name;

@SerializedName("webUrl")
private String webUrl;

@SerializedName("displayName")
private String displayName;
}



public class Sites {

@SerializedName("value")
private ArrayList<Site> sites;

}
```

And create a custom request using BaseRequest from MSGraph SDK that deserializes the returned JSON:

```
public class CustomRequest extends BaseRequest {

public CustomRequest(final String requestUrl, final IBaseClient client, final java.util.List<Option> requestOptions) {
    super(requestUrl, client, requestOptions, JsonElement.class);
}

public Sites getSites() throws ClientException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement re = send(HttpMethod.GET, null);
    Sites sites = gson.fromJson(re, Sites.class);

    return sites;
}
```

Calling `getSites` method with AsyncTask and the necessary parameters returns a collection of Site objects with the sites the signed in user can access.

I leave this question unanswered in hopes it's actually possible to do this with the OneDrive SDK.